# Tomcat several request without EJBs, Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, ejb, guice

Now i started a new application, which i divided in>
ApplicationWeb, ApplicationFramework.

The applicationWeb contains my servlets which it will  execute the logic in the ApplicationFramework side, this one will make several request in differents webservices and also ofcourse DAO transactions...
Before i was using all this with EJB which i didnt need to worry for Pools, trasactionality, concurrency and so on, but this time i want to do it in Tomcat, with POJOs, should i need in this case, a ThreadManager to manage all the request and dao access? or there will be no problem since the Servlet will create an instance for each session?
i was planning to use also Guice which im related and can get closer somehow to the DI that EJB uses.

Any ideas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Each request is handled by a separate thread. There is only a single instance of a servlet for a servlet mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Well, technically Servlet will process each request in separate thread. So you don't need to worry about concurrency at Servlet layer.

If you create your DAO and SERVICE layer as stateless (you will not store any state in fields)  you don't need to worry about concurrency at this level either (since stateless objects are thread-safe).

So in my opinion you don't need to worry about concurrency...

Comment: But thing is that i dont want to use @EJB annotations, since Tomcat cannot support it.

Comment: Yes, in short, Tomcat is a Servlet Container and for EJB you need Application Servler (like JBoss or GlassFish). So in my opinion you need some kind of Dependency Injection container. In my opinion Guice or Spring is a good choice for Tomcat.

Comment: Thats what i thought, but can thouse Dependecy Injector container, but still was wondering, how can i use Guice instead of EJB, still wont have concurrency problems in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly... If you create Service and DAO layer as stateless beans - you will not. This is more a matter of coding style then chosen framework.

Comment: But can i still creating a stateless session beans without impleting EJB? how it will be instanced?

Comment: Well, you have to look into your Dependency Injection Container's documentation.

Comment: @CristianDavidSerjeReyes Note you can use EJBs in Tomcat via Apache TomEE which is the Java EE version of Tomcat. Here's a [getting started video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lr8pxEACVRI) that shows TomEE setup in Eclipse using the Tomcat web adapter.